# django-admin cannot create project due to - zsh: /usr/local/bin/django-admin: bad interpreter

Tags: python, django, macos-big-sur

```
% source virtualenvproj/bin/activate

(virtualenvproj) % pip install django       
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./virtualenvproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in ./virtualenvproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./virtualenvproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django) (0.4.1)
Installing collected packages: django
Successfully installed django-3.1.5


(virtualenvproj) % pip freeze
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.5
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1

(virtualenvproj) % python -V
Python 3.8.0    

(virtualenvproj) % django-admin startproject myproject
zsh: /usr/local/bin/django-admin: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
```

After Big Sur Mac OS update, quite a lot of thing being messed up in my python and django environment.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for you is to change `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to `#!/usr/bin/env` python